# How to write a Spring Data JPA specification for a Postgres select from function?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a table with a JSONB column in Postgres. Let's call it `pet`.

| id | name | details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat | `{"furColour": "brown"}` |
| 2 | Dog | `{"coatColour": "black", "bark": "loud"}` |
| 3 | Parrot | `{"beakColour": "red", "featherColour": "green"}` |

I'm trying to come up with a Spring Data JPA specification that can filter the records of this table based on the attributes of the `details` column. However, I need to be able to filter by attributes ending with `Colour`, not the exact attribute name. I was able to achieve this by using a Postgres query such as this one:

```sql
select * from pet 
where exists (
    select from jsonb_each_text(details) as kv 
    where kv.key like '%Colour' 
    and kv.value = 'red');
```

I'm finding it extremely challenging to come up with a JPA specification for the above where clause. I have tried this:

```java
(root, criteria, builder) -> {
    Expression<Tuple> function = 
        builder.function("jsonb_each_text", Tuple.class, root.get("details"));
            
    // Not sure how to set alias or if it's even 
    // necessary as in my SQL
    var kv = function.alias("kv");

    var subQuery = builder.createQuery().subquery(Tuple.class).select(function);

    // I'm unable to work out how to determine this root. 
    // I cannot use Tuple as a root as it's obviously not 
    // an entity and thus I get an appropriate error.
    var functionRoot = criteria.from(Tuple.class); 

    return builder.exists(subQuery.where(builder.like(functionRoot.get("key"), "%Colour"), builder.equal(functionRoot.get("value"), "red")));
};
```

My `Pet` entity class looks like this:

```java
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

// Other imports skipped for brevity

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, Object> details = Collections.emptyMap();

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Any tips, pointers, guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining your entity class? I'm trying to replicate to see what I can try.

Comment: @CalvinP. thanks. I've updated my question with the entity class.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what happened here... I wanted to edit and endup deleting it... here is it back: https://pastebin.com/EHdSRMTu

Comment: @JorgeCampos That looks useful. Can you post it as an answer please so that we can interact with your solution? :)

Comment: I tried your solution @JorgeCampos but since the `details` column is not a joined column (it's in the same table), I get `Cannot join to attribute of basic type`.

Comment: That's the reason I didn't post as a solution, I was afraid it wouldn't work... I don't have postgresql here to test it... I will see if I can modify it

Comment: My other option is to write a database function and invoke it using criteria API but that's my last resort.

Comment: Ok, the error you provided is actually useful, now I know the code I built tried to join to a details table, which shouldn't be the case. I created another two variants of it, check it out... if they still don't work it must be some slight variant of it: https://pastebin.com/dX79z2zp

Comment: The catch about these is that the SQL should be slightly different from the original, because in your original sql you are using the database features but for JPA you need to convert it to a variant and which the JPA provider can use to the code, essentially the subquery needs a direct explicit join, from above they are cross left join with the function and a left join with the function in the subquery and it is not `exists` it is an `in`

Comment: I want to add for you helpful information based on your provided question:
"JPA doesn't natively support converting JSON or JSONB fields." as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60512855/8370915).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help @JorgeCampos. Unfortunately the 2nd option doesn't work as it gives me a `Requested attribute was not a map` error and I cannot use the first option because it uses internal Hibernate API (even if I move to JPA API, it doesn't compile). I think for now I'll write a custom DB function and revisit this later when we migrate to Spring Boot 3 and JPA 3 (Hibernate 6).

Comment: Sounds good! Hope you can find a good solution for it!

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution? because i have to do the same thing. I had a a select from function, but I don't know how do it

Comment: I ended up writing a simple Postgres function and invoking it from JPA. Looks so much neater.

Comment: ```create or replace function abcd_jsonb_key_exists(jsonb_field jsonb, key_search text, value_search text) returns bool as $$
    select exists (select from jsonb_each_text(jsonb_field) as kv where kv.key ilike key_search and kv.value ilike value_search) $$
language sql;

comment on function abcd_jsonb_key_exists is 'checks if the jsonb field with the given key and value search patterns exists';```